# proof linear maps act like matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While reading "Linear Algebra Done right" from Sheldon Axler, the author wrote a proof to show that linear maps act like matrix multiplication (3.65 for anyone who owns the book).
The exact theorem suppose $T$ $\in L(V,W)$ and $v \in V$. $v_1, ..., v_n$ basis of $V$.
Then $M(Tv) = M(T)M(v)$.

The proof is the following:

\begin{align*}
v = c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n \\
\Leftrightarrow Tv = T(c_1v1 + ... + c_nv_n) \\
\Leftrightarrow Tv = c_1Tv_1 + ... + c_nTv_n \\
\Leftrightarrow M(Tv) = c_1M(Tv_1) + ... + c_nM(Tv_n) \\
\Leftrightarrow M(Tv) = c_1M(T)_{.,1} + ... + c_nM(T)_{.,n}(1)\\
\Leftrightarrow M(Tv) = M(T)M(v)
\end{align*}

But what I don't understand is the line (1). Just in the paragraph above Axler proved that $M(T)_{.,k}=M(v_k)$. But I'm failing to grasp why $M(Tv_k)$ should be equivalent to $M(T)_{.,k}$.

Comment: Typo warning (relevant to this question) in Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd edition: On lines 2, 4, and 7 of page 85, "M(v_k)$ should be "M(Tv_k)".

Comment: The lesson here (for the student) is that even good textbooks have typos. Never trust what you don't understand.

Comment: @sheldon_axler thanks for all of you for your answers, and thanks for you sir for your book, I'm really enjoy reading and working with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. Check [this](http://linear.axler.net/LADRErrataThird.html) link out. It's the errata for Axler's book. :) In short, the lines in and above Theorem 3.64 on page 85 in Axler's book should include $\mathcal{M} (Tv_k)$, not $\mathcal{M}(v_k)$.

Comment: thanks a lot, it appears I didn't fully grasp the result that came before then. Thanks a lot for your answer.